# Thread class not updating a shared array which belongs to calling class

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, threadpool

I tried to solve this problem on leetcode and was getting stuck at 19th test-case - Timeout so I tried to solve it with multi-threading.

Please find the code below:

```java
class Solution {

    public static int[] nums;
    public static int[] answer;
    public static Thread[] threads;

    public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {

        answer = new int[nums.length];
        threads = new Thread[nums.length];    
        ThreadGroup threadgrp = new ThreadGroup("");
        
        IntStream.range(0, nums.length).forEach(i -> {
        
            threads[i] = new Threaded(threadgrp, i);
            threads[i].start();
        });
        
        while(threadgrp.activeCount() > 0) {
        }

        return answer;

    }
}
```

```java
class Threaded extends Thread {

    int i;

    Threaded(ThreadGroup obj, int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        answer[i] = getProduct(nums, i);
    }

    public int getProduct(int[] nums, int i) {

        int x = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++ ) {

            if(i != j) x = x*nums[j];

        }


        return x;
    }

}
```

I wrote the code okay I think but it appears that output I'm getting is 0,0,0,0 in the initial test case which is the just the value of answer[] array initialization.
Input for test case is {1,2,3,4}
Somehow, the threads are not able to update the answer[] array and get values from nums array. I even tried static. Earlier I was using a singleton instance of Solution.

Kindly assist.

I tried without threading and it worked fine but wasn't fast enough. Then I created a subclass and also tried with inner class for thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Solution {
    
    public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
        int[] answer = new int[nums.length];
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nums.length];    
        ThreadGroup threadgrp = new ThreadGroup("");

        IntStream.range(0, nums.length).forEach(i -> {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Threaded(nums, answer, i), "Thread " + i);
            threads[i].start();
        });
        
        while(threadgrp.activeCount() > 0){
        
        }
        
        return answer;
    }
}
    
 
class Threaded implements Runnable {
    
    private int[] nums;
    private int[] answer;
    private int i;
    
    Threaded(int[] nums, int[] answer, int i) {
        this.nums = nums;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.i = i;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        answer[i] = getProduct(nums, i);
    }
    
    private int getProduct(int[] nums, int i) {
        int x = 1;  
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {    
            if (i != j) x = x * nums[j];      
        }        
        return x;
    }
}
```

Try this senpai

Comment: I am still extending Thread not implementing Runnable and also not using "Thread " + i. But it works. Thanks for your help.